# Div display changes to hidden when I use an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jquery/javascript and I'm trying to make an animated dropdown box when I click onto a button within my navbar.

My code works within jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/2898/

But when I try to implement this within my website and refresh the page, the div disappears completely. I used inspect element and it appears to change to "display:none". I've tried changing the div to a button but still no avail. I just want the button to work! lol

Please can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

This is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 right">
    <ul id="user-bar">
       <li><div class="btn-burger" id="userlinksbox"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></div></li>
       <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

       <!----- USER LINKS BOX ----->
        <div class="user-links-box">
          <h1>Test</h1>  
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
 .user-links-box {
    height: 400px;
    width: 285px;
    padding: 15px;
    top:-400px;
    right:0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

And finally, the js I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#userlinksbox").toggle(function(){
    $('.user-links-box').animate({top:40},500);
  },function(){
    $('.user-links-box').animate({top:-400},500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Without an actual link we can't really help since the code works in the fiddle. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Can you see from dev tools the CSS class that add `display:none` do `div`?

Comment: Added my website link

Comment: is it solved? viewing your web i dont need anything disappearing, only design bug when pressing this 3-lines-menu button

Comment: Hi Ori, I was testing different functions. Still no luck though. I reset the code back to the default that's on this page. Any suggestions on re-writing the code entirely would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes :

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-links-box" style="display:none">
    <h1>Test</h1>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.user-links-box {
    height: 400px;
    width: 285px;
    padding: 15px;
    top:40px; // CHANGED HERE
    right:0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#111;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

`#userlinksbox { display: inline-block!important; }`

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#userlinksbox").click(function(){
        $('.user-links-box').slideToggle();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Is it really `#userlinksbox`?
Your fiddle tells me `#user-links-box`

Comment: Ah sorry, I updated the fiddle now. I'm no longer using the hyphens.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Barett The question obviously is "Please can someone show me where I'm going wrong?". If he just were to target the wrong element this would be the answer.

Comment: Well, he wasn't targeting the wrong element. :( This is why SO suggests using comments rather than answers, if you need clarification on the question, such as typos. Your question came up in the low quality posts queue due to the use of "?"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#userlinksbox").toggle(function(){
    $('.user-links-box').css({'display':'block'});
    $('.user-links-box').animate({top:40},500);
  },function(){
    $('.user-links-box').animate({top:-400},500);
  });
});
```

Comment: No luck, it still changes the display to none.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the `.css()` function in @Vilvan's answer outside the `.toggle()` function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userlinksbox").toggle(function(){
        $('.user-links-box').animate({top:40},500);
    },function(){
        $('.user-links-box').animate({top:-400},500);
    });  

    $('#userlinksbox').css({'display':'block'});
});
```

Comment: Still disappears. :-/ It has to be a div problem or something. Has to be.

Comment: I have edited the Selector. it was #userlinksbox instead of .user-links-box. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work. Have you checked the website link to see what's going on? If you hit refresh you can actually see it disappearing.

Comment: try this :  $('#userlinksbox').css({'display':'inline-block'}); instead of  $('#userlinksbox').css({'display':'block'});